# Does Payu money(Integration) 1.4.4 version have the permission of RECIEVE_SMS?

Tags: android, payumoney, payu

According to Google play policy the CALL & SMS permissions are not allowed,I was having the 1.2.3 version of payu money integration that automatically sets default permission(RECEIVE_SMS). Now i have updated it to 1.4.4 version...Does this version also have the same problem?